# Spark wholeTextFiles difference between shell and app

Tags: apache-spark

I've copy-pasted a line that looks like this

```
val files = sc.wholeTextFiles("file:///path/to/files/*.csv")
```

from the Spark shell, where it runs, to an application, where it does not run. Instead I get that the pattern matches 0 files even though in the shell I can see all the files and Spark reads them.

What am I missing? Is this a file permissions problem?

I'm running the app as follows:

```
spark-submit \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --files /usr/hdp/current/spark/conf/hive-site.xml \
  --num-executors 20 \
  --driver-memory 8G \
  --executor-memory 4G \
  --class com.myorg.pkg.MyApp \
  MyApp-assembly-0.1.jar
```

Comment: is your file present in local file system or hdfs?

Comment: do you provide the absolute path or a relative path?

Comment: It's on the local FS and the path is as in the mock example: absolute.

Comment: How do you run your application?

Comment: Packaged as an assembly jar (with sbt assembly) and then submitted to the cluster via `spark-submit` with the `--master yarn-cluster` option (see original question with edit).

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work, all of your executors need access to this file. If the file is not on the local filesystem for every executor then you will run into issues.

One option would be to place the file on hdfs and provide the path as `hdfs:/path/to/file.csv`. This way all of the executors have access to it.

Another option would be to pass the file in the `--files` parameter. This will ship the file out to all the executors so they all have access to it.

Comment: Yep, I figured that one out just after I had left my laptop. HDFS is then the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, what still bothers me is that in the Spark shell this works. How come the shell can deal with this? Does it only use the local node (i.e. 1 executor)?

Comment: Spark Shell works because it launches the Application Master locally where the file exists @Ian